# OrientDB: dbtype - Graph or Document

Tags: orientdb

When creating a DB in OrientDB, you can choose between Graph or Document.

I understand the conceptual difference between a Graph and a Document.  However, it seems that regardless of the choice, the DB has the same capabilities (for example, if you create a document DB you can still create vertices in the graph).

So is there really any difference between the two options? Is it a hint to OrientDB on how to initially organize the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that with "graph" the default classes `V` and `E` are created. That's it. In the next releases, we will remove this parameter because has not much sense.

Comment: Is the above still the case?  I created a "document" DB and was still able to extend class E and V?  So it looks like V and E are also in a document DB?